# How do I make a search form in Access 365

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am currently trying to make a search form for my database. I want to place it in a navigation form (so I heard I can't use a split form). I currently have a form with 4 text boxes and one combo box for a total of 5 criteria to search with a separate button for each. Underneath, is a query based on my table. This is what I have done so far

I'm hitting a wall on how to actually perform the search though. I have never used access before this project and have no idea how to use VBA (but I do know other languages). Is it possible to perform the search using macros? If not, how would I make a search sub-procedure?

Comment: See [ask]. Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you approach this is to build the search form and develop and test the search form. Get it working? You can then drop this working form into an existing “navigation form set”.

There are a gazillion ways to do this – you are quite much only limited by your imagining. However, a common setup is to create a “main” form. This main form can have a few text boxes for you to type in your search values. And then you use the wizards to create a “results” form (a nice form in which you display the results for the user to see + pick the results).

In fact, you really don’t have to use a form + sub form, but I find this often works somewhat better then placing the “criteria” boxes in the forms heading area.

So create main form – this form is unbound (not attached to any table in the system). Have fun, lay out the form anyway you want.

Then use the wizards to create a multiple items form. Get that form laid out with nice columns. Now with main form in design mode, simply drag + drop in the “display results” form.

The result is an access form that looks like this:

[image]

In above, note how the user “typed” in some criteria.

So you place some code in the text box “after” update event. It can look like this:

dim strSql          as string

strSql = "select * from tblCustomer where LastName like " & me.txtLastName 
& "*"

me.MySubFormname.Form.RecordSource = strSql

So we “build” the sql on the fly, and “stuff” the sql right into the sub form to display the results.

Note also in the above contines items form, we have a “view” or “edit” button when clicked can launch a detail form to the ONE record  you select. In my example I used a “glasses” icon for the button. The code behind that buttion is thus:

Docmd.OpenForm "frmEditDetails",,,"id = " & me!id

edit: the sql string has to be correct, so in above, it should be:

```
dim strSql          as string 

 strSql = "select * from tblCustomer where LastName like '" & me.txtLastName & "*'" 
 debug.print strSql
 me.MySubFormname.Form.RecordSource = strSql
```

So VERY little code is required. The rest is simply whatever your fancy is in terms of how you lay out the UI.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the quick response. It's all working well, except for the code. Can you explain what exactly it's doing? I think I'm setting it up wrong. The debugger throws errors at: me.MySubFormname.Form.RecordSource = strSql. I wrote it as me.MIForm(my multiple items form).Form.Query1(my Query that I pull the info from) = strSql

Comment: All the code does is create a valid SQL string. Place a debug.print "your sql" in your code to see/view the exact sql your producing. And then cut + paste the sql results into a new query you build (flip to sql view - paste in your sql and see if it works. And in the VBA code editor when you type in "me.", then VBA should pop up a valid list of controls. Remember, the name of the sub form control is what you use here - not the name of the sub form. Access "usually" names the control the same as the sub form. It is assumed that  your sub form was tested separate and displays data correctly.

Comment: see my new edit - the sql string was a bit wrong. Add the debug.print, and thus you can see/view if the sql is correct.

Comment: My debugger is still throwing errors at that last part. When I comment that part out, I don't get the SQL string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: place a debug.print strSQL in your code. When you run the code and it fails, then you can hit ctrl-g to jump to debug window. Look at the sql and then select that sql (copy), and then create  new blank query, flip into sql view mode and past in your sql - does it run? So your sql statement MUST be able to run in the standard query builder - check the syntax of the sql - is it valid and does the sql produced from the debug.print work in the query builder.

Comment: I just tried that and when I hit ctrl+g I got a box titled "Immediate" at the bottom with " select * from tblCustomer where Customer like '*' " is this the sql?

Comment: Correct - take that sql, and paste it into the query builder (flip to sql view). You can now check + test that the sql is correct and runs. (try the sql - hit the "!" I the query builder. It it works, then your sql is verified to be correct.  Remember, in the VBA coded editor let intel-sense pop up the list of choices. You want to ensure that your code uses the correct subform control (the sub form control does NOT necessary have the same name as the sub-form you dropped into the main form (so check for "child1" etc. The name of the sub form control  should pop up while coding.